# How to retrieve a control with a certain property from a collection of Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I create a menu application in an ASP.NET app like this:

```
// HTML
<td runat="server" id="container">

// C#. This logic is creating
// within a LOOP
Label l = new Label("name_blabla");
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Add(l);
container.Controls.Add(p);
```

At a given moment I assing the CSS class `myclass` to the label `l`:

```
l.CssClass="myClass";
```

So the container has only one panel containing only one label with this `myclass` name assigned.

The purpose is to get this panel from the container once all controls are inserted. I don't know the position where it is inserted. Better with LINQ.

Comment: The requirements in your question have drastically changed since you first posted it. You should refrain from doing that, as it invalidates the answers posted before your edits. I tried to catch up to the new requirements to an extent, but gave up in the end.

Comment: Your answer is right and works and is accepted. I'd better create anothoner one for my last requeriment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OfType<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to filter panels, then apply [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to project the labels inside your panels, then [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to check the CSS classes of the labels:

```
Label theLabel
    = container.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                        .SelectMany(panel => panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                        .Where(label => label.CssClass == "MyClass")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

**EDIT:** If you want to match the panel instead of the label, you can use [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
Panel thePanel
    = container.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                        .Where(panel => panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().Any(
                            label => label.CssClass == "MyClass"))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @a_maar, that's possible with `Any()`. See my updated answer.